# Using generating functions to translate a word problem into a recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

There are n job candidates that are being considered for a job and must complete a certain task to move forward. They are divided randomly into 2 groups, A and B. The interviewees in group A must take a test in one of 4 languages while those in group B must arrange themselves around a circular table and discuss one of 3 given topics (two circular arrangements are considered to be the same if each student has the same person sitting on his/her left in the two arrangements).

I am wondering how to go about translating this problem into a product of generating functions?

Any help here? I know that the number of ways to arrange people around a circular table is $(n-1)!$ but how to combine all the pieces above to come up with a product is not so clear to me...

Edit: Since the problem is poorly worded, I have edited out the last component and left it as is so the answer below is satisfactory.

Comment: Are the students in group A all taking a test in the same one of the four languages? And are those in group B all discussing the same one of the three topics? Or is each student in each group choosing a language (group A) or topic (group B) independently.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So the way the question is phrased is: they are divided randomly into A and B (A or B may be empty), and then the people in group A each take a test in one of four language, and the people in group B sit on a table to discuss one of three topics. That is all that is given. The way I understand it is that the people in A are randomly assigned one of the four tests and the people in group B are all discussing one of the three topics. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. That’s my reading of it also, but I wasn’t sure whether the source was being quoted or paraphrased or whether there might be additional contextual information that would absolutely settle the matter.

Comment: This question [was asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654115) just some hours ago. Please provide the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the candidates are divided randomly, you want exponential generating functions. For the group A task that is $\sum_{n\ge 0}4^n\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{4x}$, if we're interpreting the problem correctly. For the group B task it seems to be

$$1+\sum_{n\ge 1}3(n-1)!\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+3\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}n=1-3\ln(1-x)\;.$$

The product is $e^{4x}\big(1-\ln(1-x)\big)$, and the coefficient of $x^n$ is

$$4^n+3\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}k4^k(n-k-1)!=4^n+3\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k4^{n-k}(k-1)!\;.$$

I don't at the moment see either a series expansion of the product or a nice recurrence, and it's 3:30 a.m. here, so I'll post this in case it's of some use and take another look tomorrow.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $3^n$ instead of $3$ in the GF for the group B task?

Comment: @awkward: Not as **skidjoe** and I interpret the problem: we both read it as meaning that group B chooses a single topic for the whole group to discuss, so that it’s a three-way choice for any non-empty group B. See the comments under the question. (The extra $1$ term in the first displayed line is to account for the fact that no topic is chosen when group B is empty.) If each member of group B chooses a separate topic, there would indeed be a $3^n$ — and the problem would be even more poorly worded than I took it to be.)